# Why is C.SE question search not reliable?

Tags: support, search

I used to ask Christianity questions on Google and older type search engines. I can't recall when the Stack started showing up in search results. I enjoy reading the things I find here but it seems I get better results by asking in Google and looking for a Stack answer in the search results. Why can't question search on C.SE be as accurate as Google?

Comment: Maybe you already know this, but you can tell Google to search only a specific site. Type `site:christianity.stackexchange.com` plus your search term.

Comment: I too find the SE search engine lacking, but haven't quite put my finger on what the problem is or how it could be better.

Comment: Google knows lots of synonyms, which may give it better search results at times.

Comment: In some cases I prefer CSE's search, because I can use [advanced search options](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/searching) like limiting the search to a question (`is:question`) or tag (`[tag-name]`).

Comment: @nathaniel thanks I will try to use those tips

Comment: I sometimes use Google search to find stuff on my own website, whose search function indexes only the posts, not the comments. And I regularly use it to find Bible passages on BibleGateway when I'm not sure what translation my memory is calling up for a particular statement in the Bible. It just works better than most sites' built-in search functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to beat Google at its own game. Their search engine is their public flagship. They have whole cadres of tech geeks making sure it is the best search engine on the planet—and they don't make their search algorithms public. Google's search engine dwarfs all the other search engines in usage.

Aside from some useful site-specific search options such as @Nathaniel mentions, it's unlikely that even the combined geekdom of StackExchange will be able to out-search-algorithm Google.

Comment: Is it your opinion then  that before asking a new question we should google it to help insure our question is not already asked on the stack?

Comment: @Pam I don't. When you type in the title of a new question, the page will show you similar questions, which should sleuth out any duplicates or similar questions.

Comment: "geekdom" lol. I think if SO's collective powers could be tasked against this one thing, then actually they probably would outpace Google. Heck, a bunch of them work for Google already!